# Where do limits of integration come from in the equation of heat transfer by conduction?

Tags: thermodynamics, integration, thermal-conductivity

I was watching the third lecture of Diffrential equations on OCW. As an application, the model of heat transfer by conduction is provided. We derived this equation which models the system where $T$ is the temperature inside the object, $T_e$ is the external temperature. $T_o$ is the temperature inside at time $0$

$T(t)=e^{-kt}\int kT_e(t_1)e^{kt_1}dt_1+T_oe^{-kt}$.

It was said that in applications we convert the indefinite integral to a definite one from  time $0$ to time $t$. So, it becomes:

$T(t)=e^{-kt}\int_0^t kT_e(t_1)e^{kt_1}dt_1+T_oe^{-kt}$.

My question is, Why should we convert it into a definite integral? How to justify that step? Why is it true?  I don't see the physical meaning of that. Could any one explain why do we put limits of integrations here? I don't have much ease with physics so please, try to be clear as possible.

Comment: Where is the dt in your integral? If you integrate over $t_1$ there has to be a d$_1$ under the integral. As to the left-hand-side of your equation, what you have there? $T(t_1)$ or $T(t)$ ? I suggest you to look again at the variables.

Comment: Without thinking too much about it it should be clear that *some* limits of integration are needed, since an indefinite integral isn't a function but rather a class of functions.

Comment: Regardless of the particular application, and the certain mathematical issues Sofia pointed out for this particular application, for any integral form of equations that model real world dynamic systems, one must place constraints on where one begins and where one ends for the models to provide practical results (to get an answer). Otherwise as Javier suggests the model is just an expression.

Comment: @Sofia, I've modified the equation, It was un-intended typo, that all.

Comment: @JavierBadia, even though, Why do we choose in particular those limits? why not say, from $1$ to $t$? or any other possibility?

Comment: Could you provide some background on how that first equation was derived? Otherwise this is difficult to answer, because I don't see how it makes any sense at all to have a temperature equal to an indefinite integral. The most likely situation is that the equation is the solution to a differential equation and/or the limits of integration are implicit.

Comment: @JavierBadia, He used Newton's law of heat transfer of conviction and then turned it out to linear ODE and solved it using integrating factors and the result was the above integral. Any ways, I've got the idea  while reading in the book, elementary diffrential equations by Edwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic reason for this conversion of integrals taking place is that the term on the LHS or the left hand side is equal to the difference for the integrals of the at time t = 0 and at some time t = t. Also, this is not the only case where this is done. In many physical cases including that of linear motion, we integrate between the limits 0 and t. The key here is 'difference of the integrals' at the two points.

Comment: How do we know that LHS equals to the difference? I don't mind integrating, I'm only trying to understand why this is valid? how do we gurantee that nothing wrong is made by just choosing limits of integrating?

Comment: As clarified by docscience in a comment in your question, we must place constraints on our variables in real world systems. This is especially the case when we wish to find the value of a variable as the difference of the integrals at an initial time and a final time. In most analyses, we take the initial time to be zero, that is time when we begin analysis. The final time t is the time at which we wish to determine the value of required variable. Integrating from 0 to t gives us the generic expression. We can determine the value of the required variable at the given time by substituting t = T